# Speed of the binomial series for calculating $\sqrt{3}$

Tags: numerical-methods, binomial-theorem, newton-raphson

Calculating $\sqrt{3}$ by the binomial series for $(4-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ seems to converge very much more slowly than the Newton Raphson method for improving an initial approximation of  $\sqrt{3}\approx 2$. Is that right?

This is not a sophisticated question. I ask because I'm trying to understand an algebra textbook from 1826 (Bridge *The Elements of Algebra*).  So I have done some hand calculations with the binomial series and they seem much slower than the obvious Newton Raphson calculations although Bridge says the binomial series is very fast.  So I want to check with people who know this method.  Should I expect the binomial theorem to be slower than Newton Raphson for this problem?

Comment: Yes, you should. The binomial series converges essentially like a geometric series, the error (remainder) is roughly divided by $4$ for each additional term of the series. Newton-Raphson converges quadratically, once the error is small (with a reasonable starting value, that is immediately), you have $x_{n+1} - \sqrt{3} \approx \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} (x_n - \sqrt{3})^2$ - if you have $k$ correct digits after step $n$, you have about $2k$ correct digits after step $n+1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The binomial series, or more general, Taylor's formula in general converges at an exponential rate, here like $(1/4)^n$ (related to singulaties in the complex plane). Newton's method is in general quadratic or super-exponential fast (faster than any exponential) when you are close enough to the 'true' value.

Answer (score 4):

**Binomial Series**
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt3
&=2\sqrt{1-\frac14}\\
&=2\left(1+\frac{\frac12}{1!}\left(-\frac14\right)+\frac{\frac12\left(-\frac12\right)}{2!}\left(-\frac14\right)^2+\frac{\frac12\left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac32\right)}{3!}\left(-\frac14\right)^3+\dots\right)\\
&=-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-3)!!}{8^kk!}
\end{align}
$$
where $n!!$ is the [Double Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). Note that $(-3)!!=-1$ and $(-1)!!=1$.

Each term in the series is about $\frac14$ the size of the previous term.

---

**Newton Raphson**

[Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for $\sqrt3$ gives
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^2+3}{2x_n}
$$
For $x_n\gt0$, we have $x_{n+1}\ge\sqrt3$.

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-\sqrt3
&=\frac{\left(x_n-\sqrt3\right)^2}{2x_n}\\
&\le\frac{\left(x_n-\sqrt3\right)^2}{2\sqrt3}
\end{align}
$$
Each term in the sequence is proportional to the square of the previous term.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\root{3} & = \root{147 \over 7^{2}} = {1 \over 7}\root{144 + 3} =
{12 \over 7}\pars{1 + {1 \over 48}}^{1/2} =
{12 \over 7}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}{1 \over 48^{k}}
\end{align}

---

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}\hline
\ds{n\quad} & \ds{\quad R_{n} \equiv{12 \over 7}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1/2 \choose k}{1 \over 48^{k}}\quad} & \ds{\quad R_{n}^{2}} \\ \hline &&
\\[3mm]
\ds{0} & \ds{{12 \over 7} \approx 1.7\color{#f00}{1428571428571}} &
\ds{2.93877551020408}
\\[2mm]
\ds{1} & \ds{{97 \over 56} \approx 1.732\color{#f00}{14285714286}} &
\ds{3.00000004307126}
\\[2mm]
\ds{2} & \ds{{18623 \over 10752} \approx 1.732\color{#f00}{04985119048}} &
\ds{2.99999668700895}
\\[2mm]
\ds{3} & \ds{{18623 \over 10752} \approx 1.7320508\color{#f00}{2000248}} &
\ds{3.00000004307126}
\\[2mm]
\ds{4} & \ds{{98074093 \over 56623104} \approx 1.732050807\color{#f00}{38774}} &
\ds{2.99999999937252}
\end{array}
$$

> With *Newton-Rapson*, it's better to start with
>   $\ds{\root{3} = 2\root{3 \over 4} = 2\root{0.75}}$. Since
>   $\ds{0.75< \root{0.75} < 1}$, we start with
>   $\ds{x_{0} = {0.75 + 1 \over 2} = 0.875}$ and
>   $$
> x_{n} = \half\pars{x_{n - 1} + {0.75 \over x_{n - 1}}}\,,\qquad n \geq 1
> $$
>   With $\ds{\large 3}$ iterations we'll get $\ds{\large 17}$ right decimals
>   $$
> 2x_{3} \approx 1.73205080756887729
> $$